# Neo4j OGM and Maven -- Could not resolve dependencies for project

Tags: maven, neo4j

I have problem with building Neo4j OGM Java project. What is the problem? How to resolve it?

In build log I have errors:

```
--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ Neo4j-my ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
Copying 0 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Neo4j-my ---
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

After that I get compilation error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
neo4jCMS/entity/Person.java:[31,30] error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
neo4jCMS/entity/Person.java:[44,28] error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
2 errors 
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.471s
Finished at: Sun Aug 21 23:49:40 CEST 2016
Final Memory: 7M/150M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Neo4j-my: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
neo4jCMS/entity/Person.java:[31,30] error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
neo4jCMS/entity/Person.java:[44,28] error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My pom.xml file: https://jpst.it/MsZN

Comment: It looks like Maven do not see that in pom.xml is set Java 1.8: "<java.version>1.8</java.version>". Maven gives: "neo4jCMS/entity/Person.java:[31,30] error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)"

Comment: Netbeans shows: "package import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation do not exists": import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId; (also with Entity and Relationship).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is written using Java 1.8 or 1.7 syntax (diamond) while by default Maven Compiler plugin relies on Java 1.5 I think.

You just need to specify that in your build, like follows:

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check which directory `Java home:` points by your maven by using

```
mvn -version
```

if `Java home:` points to lower version than 1.7 then set JAVA_HOME appropriately